# Получить контент iframe на том же домене

Tags: javascript, iframe

Есть iframe к которому есть доступ, т.к. он на том же домене.
Моя задача найти первую ссылку, и поставить на нее обработчик.
Мой код работает, однако есть один момент, который я не понимаю, и бы хотел сделать более грамотно.
Мои действия:
Я ставлю MutationObserver на документ и жду когда добавится iframe.
Этот момент работает, iframe берется. 
Однако потом, чтобы получить доступ к его детям мне приходится ставить timeOut, иначе код не срабатывает (A = null). Пробовал разные фичи, вроде события contentWindow.onload, document.DOMContentLoaded, пробовал создавать еще один MutatonObserver, ничего кроме timeOut'а не работает.
Помогите пожалуйста, кто понимает в чем дело и как исправить.
Мой код:

```js
var observers = [];

if(window.top == window.self){
 var observer = new (window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver)(function(mutations) {
  for (var i = 0; i < mutations.length; i++) {
   if (mutations[i].type === 'childList') {
    parse(mutations[i].addedNodes);
   }
  }
 });

 observer.observe( document.querySelector('body'), {
  childList : true,
  subtree : true,
  attributes : false
 });

 observers.push(observer);
}
else{
 run(document);
}

function parse(nodes){
 [].forEach.call(nodes, function(node){
  if(!/http(s?):/i.test(node.src)){
   
   if(node.tagName == "IFRAME"){
    setTimeout(function(){
     run(node.contentWindow.document);
    }, 300);
    
   }
  }
 }); 
}

function run(doc){
 var a = doc.querySelector("a");
 //<...>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Видимо проходит некоторое время между появлением айфрема в DOM и появлением в нём контента. Попробуйте цеплять событие onload в самом айфрейме, и оповещать об этом родительское окно. То есть не родитель следит за iframe, а iframe оповещает родителя о готовности.